Flowtype: Partial enums
Regarding Flow enums, is it possible to have partial subsets?
For example, let's say you have the following:
enum Size {
    Mini = 'mini',
    Tiny = 'tiny',
    Small = 'small',
    Medium = 'medium',
    Large = 'large',
    Massive = 'massive'
}

Is there a one-linerish way to get a subset of this? We have quite a few use-cases where it would be handy to have variations of larger enums available.
Expected:
enum SmallSize = { Size.Tiny, Size.Mini, Size.Small }

Actual:
Parsing error: '}' expected in enum body
        Size.Mini,


Enum member names need to be unique, but the name Size has already been used before in enum SmallSize.


Flow's docs say that their enum type is not a union type - which implies that Flow doesn't not support ADT-style operations on enum types. You'll need to switch to a true union-type for that.
